# How to achieve the function that shadowsocks forwards to IEPL?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

When using shadowsocks, it only replies one interface of the Ubuntu VM. It will receive and reply the request in the same interface. In my case, I have an IEPL solution on the other interface of this VM. How can I set up to forward accepted shadowsocks traffic to IEPL? [This is the network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmoLj.png)

I wonder how to achieve such function in this Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so networking support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can probably ask on [sf] instead, but first please take [their tour](https://serverfault.com/tour) and check out [their How to Ask page](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask). Or you could consider asking on [su] or [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.